# Problems moving home partition

Tags: ubuntu, partition

I was running low in disk space on my Linux box, Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop, (specifically on my /home partition) so I added another disk to it and I am trying to move the home partition into it.

I am trying to follow the steps on this guide here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

However, when copying the files over to the new mounted partition rsync seems to fail silently. When I compare the folders, the new one is still empty.

This is the command that I am executing:

```
sudo rsync -axS --exclude='/*/.gvfs' /home/. /media/home/.
```

Has it anything to do with the encryption on my home folder?

Comment: which part fixed your problem? the EDIT?

Comment: for anyone who finds it useful, i just made use of that guide, having found the link here. i didn't need the last step, making a placeholder directory for /home, which seems designed for ubuntu users who have everything in one partition by default. since my stuff is all in different partitions, there was already a /home placeholder. i used @Josh's command below, and everything worked great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the "verbose" flag to rsync, and see what that says:

```
rsync -avxS --exclude='/*/.gvfs' /home/. /media/home/.
```

Edit your question to include the results, and we'll be able to help you further.

Also, I'm not sure why you're going with `/home/.`, try just `/home/`:

```
rsync -avxS --exclude='/*/.gvfs' /home/ /media/home/
```

**EDIT:** Also, please make sure you're *not* logged in to any user with an encrypted home directory. If all users have encrypted home directories, add a user who does not first, and use that user to copy.